# Using Linq, how to parse Xml to C# objects which only accept parameters in the constructor?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Suppose I have some XML Like this:

```
<User>
    <Name>X</Name>
    <Gender>Y</Gender>
    <ImageUrl>Z</ImageUrl>
</User>
```

and I have a class called User.

```
public class User
{
    public User(string name, string gender, string imageUrl) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Gender { get; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; }
}
```

which accepts a constructor `public User(string name, string gender, string ImageUrl)` only and does not allow set for the properties, what is the best way to parse this xml into these objects using linq and c#?

In a crude way, it is possible to create anonymous objects and then iterate over them to create the required objects. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any anonymous objects at all. Using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) you can simply select *User* nodes from your XML and create actual `User` class instances by invoking constructor with values selected from XML node:

```
// xml contains XML string, like in your sample
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var users = document.Descendants("User")
   .Select(u => new User(
       u.Element("Name").Value,
       u.Element("Gender").Value, 
       u.Element("ImageUrl").Value
   ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method that's reusable for most classes, here's something I've used in the past.

Bear in mind this uses reflection, so it's not as fast as jimmy_keen's answer anyway.  Since you mentioned 'efficient', this won't run as fast as his answer -- take it for what it's worth:

Here's the code:

```
    ConstructorInfo GetBestConstructor(XElement elm, Type itemType)
    {
        var elements = elm.Elements();

        // Get a constructor with the most parameters that
        // are provided by xml elements.
        var ctor = (
            from c in itemType.GetConstructors()
            let p = c.GetParameters()
            where
                p.Length > 0 &&
                p.Count(parm => elements.Any(e => e.Name.LocalName.Equals(parm.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) == p.Length
            select c
        )
            // Put the constructor with the most matching parameters
            // at the top of the list
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.GetParameters().Length)
        .FirstOrDefault();

        return ctor;
    }

    TType Construct<TType>(XElement elm)
    {
        var ctor = GetBestConstructor(elm, typeof(TType));
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            // We found a valid contructor!
            List<object> parameters = new List<object>();

            // Build a list of parameters, deserializing as we go.
            foreach (var p in ctor.GetParameters())
            {
                var item = elm.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName.Equals(p.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                if (item != null)
                {
                    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(p.ParameterType);
                    if (converter != null &&
                        converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
                    {
                        // Deserialize each parameter and add it.
                        var parameter = converter.ConvertFrom(item.Value);
                        parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Create the object, using each parameter we've deserialized
            // to pass to the constructor.
            return (TType)ctor.Invoke(parameters.ToArray());
        }
        return default(TType);
    }

    public class User
    {
        public User(string name, string gender, string imageUrl)
        {
            Name = name;
            Gender = gender;
            ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
        public string Gender { get; protected set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; protected set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<User>
    <Name>X</Name>
    <Gender>Y</Gender>
    <ImageUrl>Z</ImageUrl>
</User>");

        return doc
            .Descendants("User")
            .Select(u => Construct<User>(u));
    }

    static public void Main()
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var users = p.GetUsers().ToArray();
    }
```

Probably overkill for your needs, but thought I'd throw it out there anyway.

-Doug